# How to display my device speed using latitude and longitude

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms, gps, xamarin.forms.maps

after extracting the latitude and the longitude , I tried to use them to get my current speed , but all I can get is 0 ( I tried it in the bus and the train)

I tried to get my current position , and I save it in two variables , and then , I used a "Delay" function to get my second position after 1 Second , and then I calculated the distance between these two points and I calculated my speed later .

I - This is the Function to get my distance :

```cs
public double distance_on_geoid(double lat1, double lon1, double lat2, double lon2)
{
    double x = (lon2 - lon1)*(lon2 - lon1);
    double y = (lat2 - lat1)* (lat2 - lat1);
    double z = 6371 * Math.PI * 2;
    double w = z / 360;
    double xx = x + y;
    double zz = xx * z;
    double distance = Math.Sqrt(zz);
    return distance;
}
```

II - This is the Function to calculate my speed :

```cs
public double GetVitesse(double distance)
{
    double time_s = 0.27;
    double speed_kph = distance / time_s;
    return speed_kph;
}
```

III - This is how I called the functions :

```cs
var locator = CrossGeolocator.Current;
locator.DesiredAccuracy = 50;
var position = await locator.GetPositionAsync(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1));

while (true)
{
    double lat1 = position.Latitude;
    double long1 = position.Longitude;
    await Task.Delay(1000);
    double lat2 = position.Latitude;
    double long2 = position.Longitude;
    double dist = distance_on_geoid(lat1, long1, lat2, long2);
    double vits = GetVitesse(dist);

    vitesse.Text = vits.ToString();
}
```

I expect displaying the speed in my label `vitesse`.

Comment: After the `Task.Delay(1000)` you don't actually get a new position. You're just reusing the same position again, so your Lat and Long don't update. I'd start there.

Comment: You use the same position object. So the values will always be the same. You have to call `await locator.GetPositionAsync()` again for the second position. That said the `Position` object already contains a `Speed` property (m/s), is there any reason you're not using that property?

Comment: One second is a ridiculous amount of time to measure distances even with a very good GPS, let alone with the location system of a phone. Besides, you cannot translate from longitude to distance directly (it is a little bit more complicated than that). The library you are using already allows you to measure speeds, so I don't understand why you are trying to reinvent the wheel here.

Comment: Thanks guys !! I didn't notice that there's already a speed Property!!!

Comment: If you have got the solution, remember to share here :)